# Issue detected in WorkDays_Intl vba error

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working of a sub to alert deviation days, using the function NetworkDays_Intl when the app is compiling shows me this: **Run-time error 1004   Unable to get the NetworkDays_Intl property of the WorksheetFunction class**

The code is:

```
Date = Application.WorksheetFunction.NetworkDays_Intl(Sheets("Report").Range("J4"),5,1,Sheets("Parameters").Range("B5:B26"))
```

I've checked the add-ins and all are active

Comment: Your parameters look off. The 2nd should be the end date. How is `5` the end date?

Comment: If you are using ```Date``` as a variable change that name, its a builtin. Make sure ```Range("J4")``` is a proper date, the second parameter should also be a date (though 5 is a valid date, probably not what you are looking for)

Comment: I've changed the variable name and then replace the 5 with DateAdd("d",5,Sheets("Report").Range("J4"))  and nothing changed

Comment: What happens when you do the equivalent calculation as a worksheet function, i.e. in a cell `=NETWORKDAYS.INTL(....)`?

Comment: I've tested both formulas ( Workday_intl and Networkdays_intl ) and both are ok so Its really strange behavior

Comment: We don't have enough detail here to have a [reprex]. How *exactly* did you test both formulas? What is your exact `=NETWORKDAYS.INTL` formula that works and what is the result it gives?

Comment: IFERROR(WORKDAY_INTL(J4,5,1,Parameters!$B$5:$B$26),"-")  e.g  18/08/2020 in J4 and the result is 25/08/2020 and when I change the formula to NETWORKDAY_INTL and replace the number 5 to a date... the result was a number of days between this two dates

Answer (score 0):

Just convert the date in the range using CDate in this way you avoid the error when passing values as string or something else.

`CDate(Sheets("Report").Range("J4").Value)`